# How can I save an Azure ML sklearn model to a specific blob storage container?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, machine-learning-model

Saving an sklearn model to blob storage from AzureML

Simply put, I have a sklearn model in Azure ML. I want to write the model to a specific blob storage container to save it. I've already authenticated the connection to the right blob container. Per docs :

```py
# Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file_name)

# Upload the created file
with open(file=upload_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

However, this requires me to first save the model to a local file. Is there a local file store associated with AzureML?

Alternatively, could I write back to a datastore but point the datastore to a specific storage container?

Answer (score 1):

First, save your model in local as below.

```
mlflow.sklearn.save_model(
sk_model=clf,
path=os.path.join(os.path.abspath('credit_defaults_model'), "trained_model")
)
```

[image]

Here, `os.path.abspath('credit_defaults_model')` gives path to local filesystem.
There you can save the model executing above ml code.

Then you will get files highlighted in image.

Later, you upload the `model.pkl` file to blob storage.

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
connection_string = "<your connection string>"

container_name = "data"
local_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('credit_defaults_model'), "trained_model/model.pkl")
file_name = "from_ml/sklearn.pkl"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(file_name)


with  open(local_file_path, "rb") as  data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
print("File uploaded successfully!")
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Here, model is uploaded successfully to blob.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a temporary file to upload your model. You can simply pass it directly to the [upload_blob function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-upload-blob). `Data` can be a pickle, for example.